# Update the data in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am learning about Unit of work, repository and service. Now I don't know how to update data in database

How to update the data based the id?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using DataAccess;
using DataAccess.UoW;
using Model;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Service
    {
        private readonly Unit _uow;

        public Service()
        {
            _uow = new Unit();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Mdl> GetAllLogins()
        {
            var logins = _uow.Register.GetAll().ToList();

            if (logins.Any())
            {
                var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<Table_1, Mdl>();
                });

                IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
                var dest = mapper.Map<List<Table_1>, List<Mdl>>(logins);
                return dest;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public Mdl UpdateId(int Id)
        {
            var EmpId = _uow.Register.GetByID(Id);

            if(EmpId != null)
            {
                var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<Mdl, Table_1>();
                });

                IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
                var dest = mapper.Map<Mdl, Table_1>(EmpId); //Issue Arises here
                return dest;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Cannot convert from DataAccess.Table1 to Model.Mdl

Comment: What type `_uow.Register.GetByID` is returning? Is this returning `Table_1` type? Also you could put the `var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>...` inside the constructor. and the `IMapper _mapper = config.CreateMapper();` should be `private readonly IMapper _mapper` create a instance of IMapper in the constructor you can use it in all methods of your class. Just some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While mapping we need to map the Model with the table after updating you need map the table with the model

Just a small change

Do understand the concept of mapping

```
public Mdl UpdateId(int Id)
{
    var EmpId = _uow.Register.GetByID(Id);

    if(EmpId != null)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Mdl, Table_1>();
        });

        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var dest = mapper.Map<Table_1,Mdl>(EmpId);
        return dest;
    }

    return null;
}
```